# Refactoring in Java: Duplicated attributes

Tags: java, oop, refactoring

I am supposed to refactor duplicated attributes in Student class. I have Student and Professor classes as below. I am really confused about how to do refactoring with attributes. Should I add a new class, or made modifications in one of the classes. If so, how? I could not understand how to proceed with this to-do.

```
    private final String matrNr;
    private final String name;
    private final int age;
    private int semester;
    private final String email;

   
    public Student(String name, int age, String email, String matrNr, int semester) {
        this.matrNr = matrNr;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.semester = semester;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public int getSemester() {
        return semester;
    }

    public String getMatrNr() {
        return matrNr;
    }

    public void increaseSemester(){
        semester = semester + 1;
    }
}
```

And the professor is a like:

```
    private final String persNr;
    private final String name;
    private final int age;
    private final String email;

   

    public Professor(String name, int age, String email, String persNr) {
        this.persNr = persNr;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPersNr() {
        return persNr;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any kind of helps!

Comment: A Professor is not a Student, and a Student is not a professor (at least not at the same time), so you can't make one extend the other. You will need to create a `Person` class which both `Professor` and `Student` extend, and move common attributes (and behaviour if any) into the `Person` class,

Comment: @tgdavies thank you very much! this really makes a lot of sense :)  I should have thought of it at first sight.

Answer (score 2):

Your goal is to refactor duplicated attributes in the Student and Professor classes. The way to do this is to create a parent class which defines the common attributes (like "name"), and modify Student and Professor classes to extend the common parent class. In this way, both Students and Professors can have a "name", even though you have defined "name" only once in the common parent.

Below shows how you could do this with a common "Human" parent class, how the constructors would work, and how you could define a Student-only attribute (semester).

Here is a simple version a common Human class:

- common "Human" class
- each Human has a "name"
- the name is set in the constructor (so when you're creating an object) and cannot be changed later ("name" is final; also no "setHuman()")

```
class Human {
    private final String name;

    public Human(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Here's a simple Professor class:

- by definition, a Professor is a Human (`Professor extends Human`)
- when creating a Professor, you must specify the "name" (which is then passed to the Human constructor)
- once you have a Professor, you can call `getName()` (which is defined on the Human class)

```
class Professor extends Human {
    public Professor(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

Here's a simple Student class:

- Student is a little different - in addition to a name, it also has a "semester"
- when creating a Student, the constructor requires a name and semester, and the Student class itself keeps track of "semester" – so it's fine to have semester defined on Student, and name defined on Human.
- you can call `getName()` (defined on Human)
- you can call `getSemester()` (defined on Student)

```
class Student extends Human {
    private final int semester;

    public Student(String name, int semester) {
        super(name);
        this.semester = semester;
    }

    public int getSemester() {
        return semester;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose depending on the usage – what a Student represents, when it's created, if it might need to change – you might want "semester" to be modifiable. So while we could expect "name" to stay fixed (and thus, declare it "final"), perhaps you would want "semester" to allow changes. If that's the case, remove "final", and add a "setSemester(int newSemester)" (or something similar) so that you can change the semester of a Student.